# How to restore map object when fragment load second time

Tags: android, mapfragment

I have to fragments one Fragment contains Map and other one to show details of pin when user clicks on map.When user clicks on back button from Details Fragment i am overriding the back button to show map again.

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, mapfragment).commit();
```

When i am doing like this the map is reloading.I tried with addToBackStack also but no luck.Can any one suggest how to resolve it..

Answer (score 1):

Check [this](http://emuneee.com/blog/2013/01/07/saving-fragment-states/) out. You need to save the state of the fragment.

Comment: Please let me know if it helped or not.

Answer (score 1):

Use following code:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                           .add(detailFragment, "detail")
                           // Add this transaction to the back stack
                           .addToBackStack()
                           .commit();
```

Remove anything you have written in onBackPressed.

Try and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

When the `SupportMapFragment` is created, call the method `setRetainInstance()`.

```
public class MapActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap map;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map);
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    SupportMapFragment smf = (SupportMapFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    smf.setRetainInstance(true);
    smf.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    this.map = googleMap;
    // put some markers
}

}
```

For more information go [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#RetainingAnObject).